# options to get an access_token issued by identity provider , not the AWS Cognito token

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, openid, aws-amplify

I've configured authentication via federated OpenID identity provider on Amazon Cognito

so after authentification, I have authenticated & created a Cognito user with OIDC claims.

How I understand the authentification flow:
after when a user authenticates himself on the identity provider he will be redirected back to amazon Cognito hosted UI /oauth2/idpresponse with CODE from the identity provider
then Cognito uses this code (internally) to get an access token(1) to fetch user information for OIDC claims that will be saved to Cognito user.
Then Cognito creates his own access&Id tokens.

so the question - is it possible to get an access_token(1) that was issued from the identity provider, not the Cognito token?
I need to use that token to fetch some data from the API of the identity provider

appreciate any help!

Comment: Unfortunately the short answer is no. The authorization code can only be used once so even intercepting it won't really help here.